# how to check the database if contains image

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
private void readimagefromdb()

   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
   command.Connection = connection;
   string query = "select * from StudentInformation where [StudentID] = " + txtStudentID.Text + "";
   command.CommandText = query;
   OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

if (picturebox.Image == null)
{
   txtStudentFN.Text = (read["Firstname"].ToString());
}

if (picturebox.Image != null)
{
     txtStudentFN.Text = (read["Firstname"].ToString());

     byte[] image = (byte[])(read["Image"]);    
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
     StudentPicture.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

when my data got no picture i got error ERROR: unable to cast object type system.dbnull to type systembyte

i make this to prevent the error and everytime i add a new data without picture.. i can read without error . sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate. Check for null before trying to cast with `DbDataReader.IsDbNull`.  Also *don't* create SQL queries using string concatenation, that just begs for a SQL Injection attack. Use parameterized queries

Comment: ok. im sorry btw thank for info!